# Получить данные из реестра другого компьютера

Tags: c#, wmi

Я могу получить текстовые данные из реестра, но не могу получить данные в формате byte.

```
        const long HKLM = 0x80000002;//HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
        String strKey = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";  

        ManagementScope scope = fc.connect2((String)computerName);
        try
        {
            scope.Connect();
            ManagementClass registry = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), null);
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("EnumKey");
            inParams["hDefKey"] = HKLM;
            inParams["sSubKeyName"] = strKey;

            ManagementBaseObject outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("EnumKey", inParams, null);
            string[] programGuids = outParams["sNames"] as string[];

            foreach (string subKeyName in programGuids)
            {
                inParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
                inParams["hDefKey"] = HKLM;//HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
                inParams["sSubKeyName"] = strKey + @"\" + subKeyName;
                inParams["sValueName"] = "DisplayName";//Получить имя компа
                // Read Registry Value 
                outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, null);

                if (outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value != null)
                {
                    string softwareName = outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value.ToString();
                    programs.Add(softwareName+":"+(String)computerName);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            Action act1 = () => { listBox1.Items.Add("Не доступен: " + computerName); };
            Invoke(act1);
        }
        Action action = () => { kolvoPC++;  progressBar1.Value = kolvoPC; };
        Invoke(action);
```

Вот здесь я получаю DisplayName. Могу получить любые string данные, но как мне получить, например, Language или SystemComponent, которые имеют данные в формате byte?

Comment: Нужен код, который не работает.

Comment: Если я поменяю inParams["sValueName"] = "DisplayName" на inParams["sValueName"] = "SystemComponent", то он просто ничего не находит. Нужно как-то достать с реестра бинарные данные

Comment: В вопросе нужен тот код, с которым вы разбираетесь. Ну и посмотрите внимательно что вы дергаете для бинарных (!!!) данных: GetStringValue

Comment: Я на Delphi вместо "GetDWORDValue" использую. Если еще актуально. Для binary "GetBinaryValue". "GetStringValue" - только для строк...